# Eclipse CVS repository explorer

Tags: eclipse, cvs

when I want to start CVS repository explorer, it cannot connect to the server. 
I entered something like "a.b.com" as "host" and "/c/d" as repository path. I entered my username and password and "module" name correctly. Does anybody know what the problem is?

Thank you so much.

shadi :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on:

- the version of Eclipse
- the way it fails (right at the beginning or after some time like [bug 229982](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=229982) )
- what Windows/Show Views/Error log displays (is there an error message or an exception of some kind associated with the failed connection
- external factors like a new anti-virus or firewall which would block some ports previously unblocked.

For instance, do you see this kind of error message as [in this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.dsdp.tm/msg00300.html)?

```
Errors saving CVS synchronization information to disk. 
  Please fix the problems listed below and then 
  update the affected resources from the CVS repository.
Could not get input stream
Could not get input stream
Operation failed. File system input or output error
```

---

As the OP [Shadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265693/shadi) says in the comments, it was a protocol issue:

> I should have used **"`extssh`" instead of "`pserver`"**.

which is compliant with:

- [this ticket](http://fisheye4.atlassian.com/changelog/hudson/?cs=10234): "'`extssh`' is a valid protocol in CVS nowadays.",
- and the way [eclipse uses CVS](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/CVS_Howto#extssh_CVS_Setup_using_a_Firewall).

Comment: thank you so much for your help. the problem is gone now. However, when I use the Eclipse CVS repository to change a file or add a new file, it does not work. I mean the new file is not added or the available file is not updated. Do you have any idea why?
Thanks.

Comment: @Shadi: no idea right now, but if you detail your exact context, that could make a good new question for us to try solving.

Comment: Thanks VonC,
the problem is solved. I should have used "extssh" instead of "pserver".
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Shadi: thank you for your feedback. I have updated my answer to reflect your solution.